# How to define a form with WTForms package using complex validator depending on external parameter?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have defined the following custom validator:

```
class DataRequiredCustom(object):
    def __init__(self, login_signup='signup', message='Data should be provided'):
        self.login_signup = login_signup
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if self.login_signup == 'signup':
            return DataRequiredCustom(message=self.message)

data_required_custom = DataRequiredCustom
```

Now my form class:

```
class LoginRegistrationForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(1, 64), Email()])
    displayname = StringField('displayname', validators=[data_required_custom(self.login_signup), Length(1, 64)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField('Confirm password', EqualTo('password'), validators=[data_required_custom(self.login_signup)])

    submit_register = SubmitField('Register')
    submit_login = SubmitField('Log In')

    def __init__(self, login_signup='signup'):
        super(LoginRegistrationForm, self).__init__()
        self.login_signup = login_signup
```

Fields `displayname` and `password2` must not be validated if parameter `login_signup` is equal to`'signup'`. Unfortunately, passing the parameter `self.login_signup` to custom validation class `data_required_custom` produce an error:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

How to pass a parameter to validation form?

**UPDATE**
I have two following forms on my template:

```
<div class="simple-register">
    <form action="{{ url_for('auth.signup') }}" method="POST"/>
    {{ form.email(type="email") }} <br/>
    {{ form.displayname(type="text") }} <br/>
    {{ form.password(type="password") }} <br/>
    {{ form.password2(type="password") }} <br/>
    {{ form.submit_register(type="submit", value="SignUp") }}
    </form>
</div>
```

and

```
<form action="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}" method="POST">
    {{ form.email() }} <br/>
    {{ form.password() }} <br/>
    {{ form.submit_login(type="submit", value="Login"}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing self in class initialization block, where no self exists yet. Try to move your code into init method.

```
class LoginRegistrationForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, login_signup='signup'):
        super(LoginRegistrationForm, self).__init__()
        self.login_signup = login_signup
        self.email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(1, 64), Email()])
        self.displayname = StringField('displayname', validators=[data_required_custom(self.login_signup), Length(1, 64)])
        self.password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])

        self.password2 = PasswordField('Confirm password', EqualTo('password'), validators=[data_required_custom(self.login_signup)])

        self.submit_register = SubmitField('Register')
        self.submit_login = SubmitField('Log In')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Trying to render the line `{{ form.email() }}` in my template (please refer to update in my question) flask returns an error: 

**AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'call'**. 

Any suggestion?